# How can I access JSON response in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the following API call: https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=spring

I'd like to assign the entire response to a variable and then use the console to parse the response. I'm assuming I need to do something like `var x = response.body` from within the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API to call that.

And you open the Chrome Dev Tools and Network Tab.